# I do hope or I hope?

Tags: grammaticality

It is correct:
1) I do hope you will consider me for the job.
2) I hope you will consider me for the job.

If they are both correct is there any difference?

Comment: In your context, including ***do*** simply adds *emphasis* (the net effect is much the same as *I **really** hope you will consider me*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both correct. We place **do** before the verb to give emphasis as Fumble Fingers said. We can also do that in the Past Simple with did.
For example:

> I knew the truth.
>   I did know the truth.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, your use of "do" more often happens in BrE than AmE, and it is used for emphasis.

> Please **do** let us know how you get on.  *(BrE)*
>   *please be sure to let us know how you are doing / how things are going*. *(AmE)*
>
> I **do** so want you to attend my wedding.
>   *I really want you to attend my wedding.*